# zlib error installing GIT on shared hosting

Tags: git, unix, zlib

I am attempting to install git onto my UK2 shared hosting server, following this guide:

http://www.randallkent.com/development/install-git-on-a-cpanel-shared-hosting-account

I have got to the very last couple of steps 'make' & 'make install' when i receive the following error:

```
config.status: executing config.mak.autogen commands
* new build flags
CC credential-store.o
In file included from credential-store.c:1:
cache.h:19:18: warning: zlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from credential-store.c:1:
cache.h:21: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘z_stream’
make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 1
```

My hosting provider has enabled zlib compression for me but i am still unable to install git.

Is there something I am missing or is it not possible on my hosting server?

Thanks very much

Comment: From the messages its clear that `zlib.h` header is missing thus build is failing. Not sure if enabling zlib compression means the zlib headers being installed. Is there any development package for zlib i.e. header files and such which you can install on the server? Are zlib libraries (`libz.so.XXX`) available? If not you could consider installing zlib from source

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?  I am running into the same issue.  I installed zlib locally and set up $PATH, $PKG_CONFIG_PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include $HOME/local/zlib but still getting this same error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems to be  you have to install zlib.
If you are using Centos, install zlib by using `yum install zlib-devel`
If you are using Debian, install zlib by using `apt-get install zlib1g-dev`.
If you wanna get source grep it from  http://www.zlib.net/ and install it, if you do this sure you will have git in your system.
Note: If you install git from the aptitude package manager or from repositories  it will automatically install the dependencies.

Comment: in Ubuntu `apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Answer (score 4):

You only need to use ./configure --with-zlib={your zlib path}

It helped me to compile git with this option.

Comment: Actually no, you need `zlib-devel` installed not plain old `zlib`, which will fail to compile git.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with a client who is hosted on their server. But thankfully cpanel comes with a version of GIT. Its at "/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git"

You can see a fix here:
http://www.codefuel.co.uk/cpanel-git-resolved/